# File / Folder created / modified date time

Tags: windows, datetime, windows-xp

I need to understand the rules which determine a file or folder's created date time and modified date time, specifically when copying or moving files or folders from 1 NTFS partition to another NTFS partition. I need this to write a support tool which can help pick the correct file for one-click email to support team.

I need to know this specifically for Windows XP and any variations between Service Packs. I have done searches on the net and read the Microsoft article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299648

However, the article does not describe the rules when copying or moving files or folders from 1 NTFS partition to another NTFS partition.

I hope this question is sufficiently specific and will be considered as related to a programming activity. If this question does not belong to this forum, let me know which forum it belongs to.

Thanks in advance.